# Where is my mistake in derivation of total variance?

Tags: variance

I'm obviously doing something wrong here.. could someone please point it out?

By definition of variance:
$$
\mathrm{Var}[Y] = \mathrm{E}\left[(Y-\mathrm{E}Y)^2\right]
$$
By definition of total expectation:
$$
= \mathrm{E}\left[\mathrm{E}\left[(Y-\mathrm{E}Y)^2 | X \right] \right]
$$
By definition of variance:
$$
= \mathrm{E} \left[ \mathrm{Var} [Y|X] \right]
$$
which is wrong.

Comment: Law of total expectation is that $E[E[Y|X]] = E[Y]$. Law of total variance is that $var(Y) = E(var(Y|X)) + var(E(Y|X))$. If you expand out that second display, you will find it pretty easily.

Comment: I've seen the derivation on wikipedia.  My question is about where I went wrong with my attempt..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more thing,

The Conditional Variance, has one more condition, where we have conditional Expectation inside the brackets. Due to this your third statement will be incorrect

[image]

Comment: Conditional variance is $$\operatorname{var}(Y|X)=E[(Y-E[Y|X])^2|X]$$

Answer (score 1):

The expression $ \mathrm{E}\left[(Y-\mathrm{E}Y)^2 | X \right] $ isn't the variance of Y, but rather the [conditional variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_variance) of $Y$ with respect to $X$.

Comment: Isn't that what my 3rd equation shows?

Comment: @rob You called it the variance, not the conditional variance (and justified it "by definition" which doesn't *show* anything).

Comment: @rob Consider iid variates, $Z_i\sim \text{Bernoulli}(0.5),\, i=1,2$. Let $X=Z_1$. Let $Y=Z_2+X$. Think about the distinction between Var$(Y)$ and Var$(Y|X=x)$ (one is twice the other!). Note that $Y$ is the number of heads in two tosses of a fair coin ($Z_1+Z_2$), but if you condition on $X$, then $(Y|X=x)$ is simply a constant ($x$) plus the number of heads in *one* toss of a fair coin ($Z_2+x$).

Comment: While @Glen_b's example is good, I'd recommend just taking the time to read up about conditional variance (wiki is an ok source).